# Eager initialize object in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to declare my android sqlite migrations in `object` declarations. Each extends the interface `Migration`, and I want to have each one register themselves upon initialization with the `Migrator` object, which being an object, is also a singleton. Unfortunately (I'm realizing this late) kotlin objects are lazily initialized, so my migrations have to be used somewhere to register themselves.

I can accept having to use reflections or annotations, but have no bearing for if that's a good idea or how to follow convention going that direction.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Simply adding a class without actually using it anywhere should not change the behavior of your code. I'd advise to instead keep a list of migrations manually or create an enum class implementing the migration interface. You could then access all migrations using Enum.values.

Comment: @ChristianBrüggemann In general I would agree, however I'm not simply adding a class without actually using it anywhere. I am explicitly calling an initialize/register method that does this, and I'd prefer to make it so that a Migration cannot accidentally be left un-registered. This would be safer than writing a perfectly good migration that does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Simply writing the object name into your main function (or whereever you want to force the initialization) works:

```
//Main.kt
fun main() {
    EagerObject
    //...
}

//EagerObject.kt
object EagerObject {
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is clumsy as you might forget to add the class to that method. The class should force the eager load itself.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can switch from object declarations to object expressions with global variables:

Eager:

```
val A = object {
    init { println("eager") }
}
```

Lazy:

```
object A {
    init { println("lazy") }
}
```

Comment: This won't work as well: files with top-level declarations get translated to `FileNameKt` classes, which are (as usual in JVM) initialized lazily.

Comment: @AlexeyAndreev that's what I'm seeing when I try this out.

Comment: For me it is working. Maybe because I'm using other functions from the same file (so the whole file gets loaded).

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see why you couldn't add an `init` block to your `Migrator` class, that way you can always see what migrations are being registered and ensure they are registered when the migrator gets referenced.

Something like this could work (or just a list.add call, depends on how you would register them).

```kotlin
object Migrator {
    init {
        listOf(UpdateNames, TableRename).forEach(Migration::register)

        // Or, as I said, something like this would make more sense
        migrations = buildList {
            add(UpdateNames)
            add(TableRename)
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

I hope this makes my idea clear, I wrote this on my phone at 2am so this might as well not compile. Sorry in advance :)

Comment: But that requires that every `Migration` is registered in the `Migrator`, it doesn't register *itself*. This is especially a problem when the `Migrator` is in a library where dependencies flow a single way.

Comment: Then i would say if they had to register themselves, either add annotations and use some eager lookups to objects that have the annotation, or make sure you register all your migrations before using the migrator at all. Since the migrator is a singleton (which is odd to me) i dont see why not.

Comment: "either add annotations and use some eager lookups to objects that have the annotation" how would that work?

Comment: You could do some kind of scanning of the classpath for classes with the annotation. There are libraries to do that for you, or you could write your own implementation with ASM or Javassist. A good lib seems to be https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Comment: Isn't there that gets autoloaded from the module when the JVM loads the program?